# Mysql: Getting value from other table (left join?)

Tags: mysql, join

I do have a mysql question. It's kinda hard to explain, but I'll give this a shot.

So, I do have one table named "FOODS". Every item in it has its unique ID.

Then, there's another table named "EATERS". Every eater has his own ID, too. The EATERs table has a field in it called "atefood", where the ID of the corresponding entry of the table FOOD is stored.

There can be multiple entries in the EATERs table with the same "atefood" ID. Let's pretend I am a eater and I am stored inside the EATER table with my current SESSION ID.

Now, I wanna show up all foods I ate, but every food only once.

Hope this was reasonable :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: accepting answer increases the reputation so that community can trust you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM eaters as e 
LEFT JOIN foods as f on e.food_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.id
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from FOODS inner join eaters on eaters.atefood = foods.id where eaters.session = [session id]